# Can you insert one audio file into another at specific time with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

My use case is to have an audio file that I need to add to another audio file at a specific time.
For example, the first file will be 1 hour long the second file 5 seconds long, and I want to insert it in the 30 minutes of the first time. The final file should be 1 hour 5 seconds long.

If that is not possible with ffmpeg maybe there is other cmd tool that can do the described thing?

Comment: You could trim the audio twice, once taking the first N seconds and the other taking the back (T-N) seconds. Then make a third pass to put the three segments together in the desired order.

Comment: That is the current solution, I was thinking if there is a `better` way for doing that.

Comment: If you like, edit the question to add what you've already found/tried/thought of and what improvement(s) you're looking for.